# How to send information to a REST server via url PHP

Tags: php, html, httprequest

I have been given a URL that I need PHP to post data to, anonymously, without the end user knowing about it.

The exact structure is:

```
https://example.com/api/rest/example/createSubscription?email=1@1.com&subscriberNumber=12345JD&subscriberGroup=shop&firstName=Joe&lastName=Bloggs&offerCode=ex1&licenseParameters="STARTDATE%3D2014-08-11%26ENDDATE%3D2014-09-11"
```

Obviously this is a dynamic URL and I have set it up to be. I am not sure about the best way to approach this issue. Would it be a `PUT` `http_request`? I have tried that using the following but it returns a 400 error.

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api/rest/example/createSubscription?email=1@1.com&subscriberNumber=12345JD&subscriberGroup=shop&firstName=Joe&lastName=Bloggs&offerCode=ex1&licenseParameters="STARTDATE%3D2014-08-11%26ENDDATE%3D2014-09-11"';
$options = array(
  'method' => 'PUT',
  'timeout' => 15,
  'header' => "Content-type: html/txt",
);
$response = http_request($url, $options);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a 400 and not a 401?

Comment: actually its a 500 internal server error

Comment: It would be a http request for sure. Which method you should use is told in the documentation of the service. It may be POST or PUT depending on the purpose (in theory) and on the implementation (in practice). BTW I suggest to start using a good http client such as Guzzle, so when in the future you will need more functionalities you're prepared for!

Comment: I asked because when I hit the URL that you had before you edited it, I'm getting a 401, along with an XML response stating that "Authentication Required to use REST API".

Comment: Another BTW: that url doesn't seem to be a REST endpoint. The url in a REST implementation should represent a resource and not an action

Comment: The authentication is automatic from the IP that i am accessing it from, which is why you will get that issue. The thing is if i paste that url into a browser with proper formatted fields that data will be stored in the database. All i need to do is get it working with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your last comment, if the subscription is created simply opening the url in the browser then it is a GET request.

You can perform a GET request using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Aha perfect, that makes sense then as file_get_contents accesses the url. Worls like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It's really strange you use PUT method with GET paramater.

After checking php manual [here](http://php.net//manual/en/function.http-request.php) you don't use correctly this methode. that's why the server can't understand your request.

you can look after [this function](http://php.net//manual/fr/function.http-put-data.php) to do a PUT request